# kendo ui data grid - firebase

Tags: kendo-ui, rest-firebase

I'm using kendo ui data grid with a firebase (rest json response). The structure can contain multiple objects. However, these objects are not in a standard array format. See my json file below:

```
{
    "users": {
        "contactdetails": {
            "email": "johnlittle@email.com"
        },
        "firstname": "John",
        "id": 1,
        "surname": "Little"
    }
}
```

I am able to read firstname and surname onto the grids column but cannot get to the email object.

This is my schema definition:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        fields: {
                id: {type: "number"},
                firstname: {type: "string"},
                surname: {type: "string"},
                email: {type: "string"} 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, u can not specify nested object to schema model definition. One way is you can use column template for email column.

```
columns: [
    { field: "firstname", title: "FirstName" }, 
    { field: "surname", title: "Surename" },
    { title: "Email", template: "#= data.contactdetails.email #" },
],
```

Comment: Japi you're a star! thank you! i just needed to add quotes and worked right away. { field: "Email", title: "email", template: "#= data.contactdetails.email #" }

Comment: Glad to hear. I will edit my answer and add quotes to template.